# Phonegap - SAP BSP Application - fails to load with Login pop-up

Tags: cordova, sap-bsp

In a Phonegap application, i open an external web app using **window.location.href** in body's onload event. It is working good with other urls like google.com and facebook.com. But i have to open my SAP Bsp application like this.

When i open my SAP BSP app, it will ask login credentials in popup like below.

*screenshot taken from windows OS.*

[image]

phone gap is not reacting anything for this case. If i disable this popup in my SAP System, app loads good. But i need to enable this popup.

Any help?

Comment: Is the screenshot missing?

Comment: Yes this screenshot screen is not popping up.

Comment: - ok - disregard this. Is just my proxy blocking the image host site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now you can not login like this in phonegap. Phonegap doesn't support system popups. You should create your own HTML login screen to do this.

View this [Phonegap Thread](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_sap_bsp_application_fails_to_load_with_login_pop_up?utm_content=topic_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=reply_notification) for more info.